# What is the best way to relate product to Account?

Tags: architecture

Here is the use case. We have a bunch of subscription products that we sell. There is relatively no sales process involved. They come in sign up for the product and they are converted into accounts.

We want to see which all products they have subscribed for on the account level itself. What would be the best way to design this?

i am thinking of having a junction object to Account and product. Is having this kind of junction objects normal in these kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider just using [Assets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=assets_def.htm&type=5), which is a many-to-many relationship between accounts and products. You can customize this object to show things you might be interested in, like subscription length, cost, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Looks like that's what i had wanted

Answer (score 1):

Users can signed up for products on Opportunity. Products will be stored in Opportunity as Opportunity Products (OpportunityLineItem) and once Opportunity is closed, you can convert your prospect business account to the customer account and the same time you can create Assets under opportunity. 
In Opportunity products, you can store all information like Rate, number of products etc.

I know, for that you have to setup a process but believe me, at some point you have to setup this process. Salesforce is built for Sales and Services Process.

Comment: Thanks, i had suggested to the client but they wanted to avoid the extra step